# jQuery plugin loaded but i got TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am using jQuery 3.x and Infinite Scroll 3.x (https://infinite-scroll.com) in my online shop. The online shop software I am using is called Shopify. I like it so far, but I have a big issue with my javascripts I am using. I want to use the Infinite Scroll, but all I got is a

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).infiniteScroll is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).infiniteScroll is not a function

All I did is this the code scnippet below. When I am trying to paste it in my online shop page, I got the error above, but when I create a local `index.html` file and try the exact same code snippet, I got **no error**.

I checked already that both scripts are loaded, I even thought it might be a timeout problem, so I did a timeout just before I run the `.infinteScroll` method, but still, the error above.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').infiniteScroll({
            // options
            path: '.pagination__next',
            append: '.post',
            history: false,
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Move jquery include on top of infinite scroll include.

Comment: Just swap the order of JS. Have JQuery as the first JS and it will work.

Comment: My bad, copy paste failure. I was just desperate that's why I tried to swap both, now the code snippet is the correct one.

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Comment: Here we go: https://www.eat4fit.ch/pages/filter

Comment: It has to be a Shopify issue, but I can't handle it I guess, but maybe there is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have loaded jQuery more than once in your website. Which may create conflict. Clean it up and load jQuery only once in your theme. Load all jQuery plugins after that.

[image]

[image]

[image]